# I cant get the tilbakemelding methods to return true when the data in mySQL is true(1) and return false when the data in mySQL is false(0)

Tags: java-ee-6

This is a method in TilbakemeldingBean and should list data from mysql database table "Godkjenning" (Wich is boolean) and should return false when it's false(0) and true when its true(1)

```
@Override
public boolean Godkjenning(String godkjentIkkegodkjent ){
    List<Tilbakemelding> tilbakemeldingListe = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tilbakemelding t WHERE t.Godkjenning LIKE :godkjenning" )
    .setParameter("godkjenning", godkjentIkkegodkjent)
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getResultList();
    System.out.println("Modul" + godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    if(tilbakemeldingListe.equals(false)){
        return true;
    }else {
    return false;
}

}
```

This is a method in main that should just post the results in a output tab

```
public static boolean Godkjenning(String godkjentIkkegodkjent){
    System.out.println(godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    boolean result = TilbakemeldingRemote.Godkjenning(godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    System.out.println("Modulen er " + result);
    return result;
}
```

This is a method in my GUI file that should open a new messagedialog saying "Modul er godkjent" when main.godkjenning = true and "Modul er ikke godkjent" when its = to false.

```
  private void åpneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

if(Main.Godkjenning(null)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tilbakeside, "Modul er godkjent");

}
else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tilbakeside, "Modul er ikke godkjent");
}

}
```

Comment: Why would a `List<Tilbakemelding>` ever equal `false`?

Comment: Because tilbakemeldingListe create a list from my database : "SELECT t FROM Tilbakemelding t WHERE t.Godkjenning LIKE :godkjenning" ). Here I can set Godkjenning to either false(0) or true(1).

Comment: I am not actually a Java user, but it seems to me your list should either contain one or more instances of `Tilbakemelding`, or null. If `TilbakeMelding` is of type Boolean you might try `if(tilbakemeldingListe[0].equals(false))` instead.

Comment: Hmmm, if I used this if sentence if(tilbakemeldingListe[0].equals(false)), it says my tilbakemeldingListe was found but array requiered, I guess this comes from the []

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered in the other question you have made: [Trying to make this method to return true if the string equals to "godkjent" and false if not. This is linked up with my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046660/trying-to-make-this-method-to-return-true-if-the-string-equals-to-godkjent-and/35312563#35312563)

I will edit the method *Godkjenning* like this:

```
@Override
public boolean Godkjenning(String godkjentIkkegodkjent) {
    /*now the query matches cases and the 'LIKE' statement will work correctly
    having the '%' char before and after the string */
    List<Tilbakemelding> tilbakemeldingListe = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tilbakemelding t WHERE UPPER(t.Godkjenning) LIKE UPPER(?)")
    .setString(0, "%"+godkjentIkkegodkjent+"%")
    .getResultList();

    System.out.println("godkjenning" + godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    /*here you have to iterate the list to find if there is the string inside*/
    for(Tilbakemelding element : tilbakemeldingListe){
    /*if you want not to consider the case, you have to use the equalsIgnoreCase statement*/
        if(element.getGodkjenning().equals("Godkjent")){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Always assuming that your Tilbakemelding entity has a getGodkjenning() method