# Trying to make this method to return true if the string equals to "godkjent" and false if not. This is linked up with my database

Tags: java-ee-6

This method is supposed to make a list from my database (Godkjenning), and I want it to return true if ive written ("Godkjent") in my database and false if not.

```
 public boolean GodkjenningT(String godkjentIkkegodkjent) {
    List<Tilbakemelding> tilbakemeldingListe = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tilbakemelding t WHERE t.Godkjenning LIKE :godkjenning" )
    .setParameter("godkjenning", godkjentIkkegodkjent )   
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getResultList();
    System.out.println("godkjenning" + godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    if(tilbakemeldingListe.equals("Godkjent")){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will edit the code like this:

```
public boolean GodkjenningT(String godkjentIkkegodkjent) {
    /*now the query matches cases and the 'LIKE' statement will work correctly
    having the '%' char before and after the string */
    List<Tilbakemelding> tilbakemeldingListe = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT t FROM Tilbakemelding t WHERE UPPER(t.Godkjenning) LIKE UPPER(?)")
    .setString(0, "%"+godkjentIkkegodkjent+"%")
    .getResultList();

    System.out.println("godkjenning" + godkjentIkkegodkjent);
    /*here you have to iterate the list to find if there is the string inside*/
    for(Tilbakemelding element : tilbakemeldingListe){
    /*if you want not to consider the case, you have to use the equalsIgnoreCase statement*/
        if(element.getGodkjenning().equals("Godkjent")){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

But, can you please post the implementation of the class: Tilbakemelding? I've supposed your Tilbakemelding entity (is that an entity? :)) has a getGodkjenning() method to complete my code.